# Rails upgrade 3.2.* to 4 Does not show all user attributes in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Kind of an odd bug I am running into.  Working on upgrading a Rails app from 3.2.22.1 tp 4.2.11.3.  Everything is working pretty well.  Test suite is passing on green.  However when I go into the rails console and do `user = User.new` or list the attributes using `User.new.attributes` I am only getting a few of the fields returned.

Specifically

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('XXxxXXxxxxXXXxXX'),
 "email"=>"",
 "encrypted_password"=>"",
 "sign_in_count"=>0,
 "time_zone"=>"Central Time (US & Canada)",
 "admin"=>false}
```

This list should be much larger, for example, it is excluding all Devise fields like `last_sign_in_at` or any of them.  Here is what it looks like, the same command, run on our production server which is the previous version of rails

```
_id: xxxXXXxxxXXXXxXXXXxx, 
invited_by_type: nil, 
invited_by_field: nil, 
invited_by_id: nil, 
email: "", 
encrypted_password: "", 
reset_password_token: nil, 
reset_password_sent_at: nil, 
remember_created_at: nil, 
sign_in_count: 0, 
current_sign_in_at: nil, 
last_sign_in_at: nil, 
current_sign_in_ip: nil, 
last_sign_in_ip: nil, 
confirmation_token: nil, 
confirmed_at: nil, 
confirmation_sent_at: nil, 
unconfirmed_email: nil, 
invitation_token: nil, 
invitation_created_at: nil, 
invitation_sent_at: nil,
invitation_accepted_at: nil, 
invitation_limit: nil, 
name: nil, 
time_zone: "Central Time (US & Canada)", 
admin: false
```

I am worried that there is something failing silently and I am not detecting it.  I can save the unlisted values in the console, but it does not show them to me, which is not how it worked previously.

Anyone understand why this is happening?

specific versions are:

1. mongid -> 5.0.1
2. devise -> 4.7.2
3. Rails -> 4.2.11.3

Comment: You haven't set any of the fields, why do you expect them to be returned?

Comment: Do you mean fields with values in them?  If I try to return a user that exists it still only shows these, even if they have (for example) an `invitation_accepted_at` value.  But the behavior it did previously is if I run `user = User.new` it will then show the empty record with all the fields.  Now it only shows these fields, it also only shows these fields if a user has values in other ones.

Comment: If you want to ask about users with attributes, edit your question accordingly. Otherwise you are getting, I assume, whatever attributes were defaulted through various mechanisms, which seems like logical behavior.

Comment: I mention it in the title and also specifically mention it in the question, not sure what else you would like to see.

Answer (score -1):

Latest version of Mongoid does not include attributes that were never written in `attributes`.

Unless you have references to documentation that claims that Mongoid would return attributes that were never written, you are experiencing expected behavior.

Comment: What does "that were never written in attributes" mean exactly? What process is that referring to? I was unable to find anything in the documentation referring to this.